# OpenCV Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, linker-errors

I've installed OpenCV 4.0.0 with this command

```
brew install hybridgroup/tools/opencv
```

And I'm trying to compile simple program which loads image from filesystem into `cv::Mat`.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main() {
    auto img = cv::imread("/Users/peter/Dektop/source.png");
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm keep getting this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, int)", referenced from:
>   _main in ccw6DQpj.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm compiling with this command. GCC 8.2.0.

```
g++-8 main.cpp -std=c++17 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Comment: Gcc changed its binary representation of `std::string` since copy-on-write was no longer allowed, are you sure the library you have uses the same representation?

Comment: Check also my last answer there is the library exists.

Comment: Note: Looks like this changed from gcc-5 on, do you know how the opencv4 library got build? (Gcc4, Gcc5 or Clang with libcxx?)

Comment: @JVApen I believe it was clang with libcxx. I've found this information in INSTALL_RECEIPT.json.

Comment: Are you sure the file name is `opencv4` and not `opencv4.pc` for `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4.pc`?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi 100% sure.

Comment: I tried :) If you decide to compile it by yourself let me know. I recently have done it

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I've tried to compile OpenCV. I've deleted `c++` symlink which was pointing on built-in Apple clang and created new one pointing to GCC 8.2.0. Compilation failed with a lot of errors in `.mm` files.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong or did no understand but if you have installed it with brew you did not compiled it...anyway instead of symlinking which is a mess on osx you can also keep it in a local folder  and referencing it during conpilation for example with a Makefile. I will try to post an answer with what I used for symlinking and also for having a local compiled folder if that's useful for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the answers in the comments, you have a binary incompatible version of the STL.

OpenCV4 is build with libc++, which defines the symbol of `string` as `std::v1::basic_string`, while libstdc++ (default of GCC), uses `std::__cxx11::basic_string`

At compile time, you don't know the difference between these 2 usages, as you are using the same interface. However, the implementation is different.
As you are calling, a function that requires such string, you'll need to compile with the same version of the STL.

I'm sure that for Clang, you can pass `-stdlib=libc++` to indicate this version of the STL, I haven't tried it with GCC.